# Why is this function an injective immersion? [Lemma 6.14 in Lee, Intro to Smooth Manifolds]

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

In Lemma 6.14 (Page 133) of J.M.Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* we consider the following:

> Let $M$ be a smooth n-manifold and suppose $F : M \to \mathbb{R}^N$ is
> an arbitrary smooth embedding of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^N$. Further, let
> $G$ be a diffeomorphism taking $\mathbb{R}^N$ to the unit ball
> $\mathbb{B}^N$. Finally, suppose $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth
> exhaustion function, i.e. $f^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ is compact in $M$ for
> all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Define the map $\Psi : M \to \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}$ by $\Psi(p) := (G\circ F (p), f(p))$.

It is claimed, that $\Psi$ is again a smooth embedding, i.e. a smooth injective immersion that is also a proper map (Lee, Prop 4.22). Obviously, $G \circ F$ is again an embedding. So $G \circ F$ is in particular an injective immersion. But I don't understand why $\Psi$ has to be injective or an immersion. This would require the smooth exhaustion function to be injective and an immersion too, but I don't see at all how this can be followed from its defining property, i.e. that $f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is compact in $M$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is this step obvious?

Comment: Well if a function is 1-1 in one of its variables, then it's 1-1 right?  It's smooth in both variables; not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnSamples: I'm a bit confused by your comment. The function $f(x,y) := (x^3, y^2)$ is not injective. For example $f(0,1) = f(0,-1)$. However, $x^2$ is injective. So it's not enough for one coordinate function to be injective. What parts am I confusing?

Comment: That's two variables going to two variables.  Here you have one variable, $p$, varying across $M$.  The 1-1 function for you is $G \circ F$.  I mean, if I give you two points in $M$, say $p_1$ and $p_2$, and $\Psi(p_1) = \Psi(p_2)$, then they have to agree in the first coordinate.  But that's impossible unless $p_1 = p_2$.  Because as you say, $G \circ F$ is an embedding, right?

Comment: Oh, thanks, John. I get your point now. As $M$ is an n-manifold I was somehow thinking of $p$ as something like $x_1, ..., x_n$...

Comment: It's a weird book.  It goes very, very slow for the first 8 chapters, then gets very serious, especially toward the end.  I had trouble with it because I was bad with all those computations and there weren't many examples; it seems to be a somewhat random game of leap-frog through medium-big theorems, without giving a lot of practice with the calculus aspects.  It's very readable tho.